# GPS signal tracking

Tags: matlab, tracking

I have a complex input signal of 300 ms at baseband. I have already performed acquisition on this signal and acquired four GPS satellites and have the code phase and Doppler frequency of each of them.

Now for tracking I am following Kai Borre's MATLAB code for a GPS software receiver. But, this code is written for a real input signal at IF (intermediate frequency).

Now I need my signal (which is currently on baseband (zero-IF)), to be at 1.5 MHz IF (intermediate frequency).

Is it practically possible to change the complex signal at baseband to a real signal at IF (1.5 MHz) without losing the information on imaginary part? My sampling rate is 5 MHz.

Comment: Mix it down numerically to complex baseband! That's but a multiplication with $e^{-j2\pi f_{IF} t}$; the values of $f_{IF}$ and $t$ both depending on both the IF frequency and sample rate.

Comment: Thanks,
I already have the signal at complex baseband. but I have a code for a signal at IF frequency. Now I have two choices: 1: either I bring my baseband signal to IF which I think is practically not possible. 
2: I make changes in the code so that it works for baseband signal. 

Which RF frontend can I use to receive signals at IF frequency? I tried RTLSDR and USRP frontends and both gives output at baseband.

Comment: well, then mix up by multiplication with $e^{j2\pi f_{IF}t}$ (you might need to interpolate to a sufficient sampling rate first), and then throw away imaginary part.

Comment: I tried doing that as well but by throwing away the imaginary part the data is being lost. And the acquisition stops working as well.
Which RF frontend can I use to receive signals at IF frequency? I tried RTLSDR and USRP frontends and both gives output at baseband.

Comment: well, if throwing away the imaginary part means you lose data, you haven't properly mixed (or have another problem somewhere). What's your baseband signal sampling rate, what is the IF sampling rate that you need? Did you interpolate to the latter properly before mixing up?

Comment: multiply your real input by a cos for I and sin for Q,has to be driven down to baseband,hence is necessary to know what your IF is and multiply by the same freq.Eg if your IF is at 3KHz then your sin and cos should also be at 3KHz,as soon as your signal is around zero,try correlations etc.

Comment: @Priyanka.P can you edit your question to tell us exactly what you're doing when mixing, and *how* that fails?

Comment: Hello Marcus, I have edited my question. My baseband sampling rate is 5 MHz and I need 1.5 MHz IF.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of examples on the web for GPS signal tracking at baseband. Look for ["SoftGNSS" on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=softgnss).

As far as converting from complex baseband to real IF, it's the opposite as what receivers normally do.
You can certainly modulate a signal from complex baseband to real IF by multiplying the real part by [image: cos2pift] and the imaginary part by [image: -sin2pift] and then add them together, [like normal transmitters do](https://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/baseband-up-and-downconversion-and-iq-modulation.html).